# php link modified to direct to specific 'home'

Tags: php

```
             <?php if ($logo): ?>
      <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>
     " rel="home" id="logo" class="logo">
        <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
      </a>
```

I want the link to go to a different 'home' , one in root domain which is interesting because the modified theme in root page.tpl.php is set to home and the subdomain modified is also set the same but as pertaining to subdomain which means if I knew how to write php I am sure there is code to change the direction of 'home'....?

Comment: SORRY FOR CONFUSION haha

Comment: different home ? What do you means by that ? or you are saying different page

Comment: my root modified goes to home my.net but my subdomain goes to mysub.net and i want it to go to my.net :)

Comment: but still use the term 'home'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are  you expect something similar, like, based on the `$subdomain` you can differentiate the main domain or subdomain, provide the link accordingly

```
    <?php
           preg_match('/^(?:www\.)?(?:(.+)\.)?(.+\..+)$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $matches);

            $SubDomain =  $matches[1];               
            if($SubDomain!=''){             

                // do your stuff here 
            }       
    ?>
```

Comment: don't actually know what to put where as i don't write php!

Comment: In `if` condition, you can use the place to navigate i.e link. else part normal home page